# SQL Group By Query to return the output in a desired format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table detailtable like below where Value is Int and rest of the column are Varchar

```
+------+------+--------+---------+-------+
| Name | City | postal | country | value |
+------+------+--------+---------+-------+
| Adam | hyd  | 500000 | India   |    10 |
| eve  | hyd  | 500000 | India   |    20 |
| Adam | Aus  | 200000 | India   |    30 |
| Adam | Aus  | 200000 | India   |    40 |
| Scott| Aus  | 400000 | India   |    90 |
+------+------+--------+---------+-------+
```

I want to write a Query such that i get the following output

```
+---------+------+--------+---------+
|  Name   | City | postal | country |
+---------+------+--------+---------+
| Various | hyd  | 500000 | India   |
| Adam    | Aus  | 200000 | India   |
| Scott   | Aus  | 400000 | India   | 
+---------+------+--------+---------+
```

> When 2 records have same city, postal,country, Name should be Various
>
> and when Name, city, postal and country are same then name should be
> actual name
>
> In case we have distinct city, postal, country pair then name will be actual name

```
select City,Postal,country from detailtable group by City,Postal,country having count(*)>1
```

returns me the data set (City,Postal,country) which are having more than one occurance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `case` expression with aggregation functions:

```
select (case when min(name) = max(name) then min(name)
             else 'various'
        end) as name, City, Postal, country
from detailtable
group by City, Postal, country ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `case` expression with `count` as follows:

```
select  count(distinct name) = 1 then min(name) else 'various' end as name, 
        city, postal, country
from detailtable t
group by City, Postal, country;
```